# to_csv, Where am I wrong

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import csv

odata = pd.read_csv('email.csv')
data = odata.drop('content', axis=1, inplace=True)
data.to_csv('email-out.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```

And I got error like that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cut.py", line 7, in <module>
    data.to_csv('email-out.csv', index=False, sep=',')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Where am I wrong?
help me..please

Comment: Show us line 7 and the full error.

Comment: line 7 is line 6, sorry, I deleted the empty line

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cut.py", line 7, in <module>
    data.to_csv('email-out.csv', index=False, sep=',')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Comment: The problem is simple. You are calling `.to_csv` on `odata.drop`. It should be `pd` instead which is `pandas`.

Comment: Can you inspect your dataframe in line 6. See what does it have. Is it a valid dataframe. If data is an instance of pandas, it should work.

Comment: You need to read up the documentation for the `drop()` method (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop). If `inplace` is set, it performs the operation in-place and returns `None` (instead of returning a new dataset).

Comment: thank you very much, I got it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change this line:

```
data = odata.drop('content', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

to this:

```
data = odata.drop('content', axis=1)
```

The `inplace` flag causes the operation to happen in-place and return `None`, instead of creating a new dataframe.

If you really *do* want the drop to happen in place, the alternative is to replace your code with something like the following:

```
odata = pd.read_csv('email.csv')
odata.drop('content', axis=1, inplace=True)
odata.to_csv('email-out.csv', index=False, sep=',')
```

Please refer to [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas.DataFrame.drop) for more info.

Comment: I got it！ Thank you very much

Comment: @Mac why does drop in place change whether pandas considers ```odata``` a dataframe or not?